# Select a record that has a duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I'd like to select all records from a table (`names`) where `lastname` is not unique. Preferably I would like to delete all records that are duplicates.

How would this be done? Assume that I **don't** want to rerun one query multiple times until it quits.

Comment: When deleting duplicates, is there a particular record you wish to keep?  IE: The one with lowest ID value, etc?

Comment: @OMG P: No, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way to delete duplicate records is my issuing a very simple command.

ALTER IGNORE TABLE [TABLENAME] ADD UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQUE_INDEX` ([FIELDNAME])

This will lock the table, if this is an issue, try:

delete t1 from table1 t1, table2 t2
where table1.duplicate_field= table2.duplicate_field (add more if need ie. and  table.duplicate_field2=table2.duplicate_field2)
and table1.unique_field > table2.unique_field
and breakup into ranges to run faster

Comment: Locking the table isn't an issue. The issue is there already duplicate rows.

Comment: If locking is not an issue, then executing ALTER IGNORE TABLE [TABLENAME] ADD UNIQUE INDEX UNIQUE_INDEX ([FIELDNAME]) will rebuild the table and remove the duplicate records.

Comment: You can't apply a constraint if the data doesn't satisfy it - your suggestion would not work.

Comment: +1 and accepted. Locked the table temporarily and went to work. No duplicates and no more will be added.

Comment: OMG, it does work. The IGNORE is the key part of what you are missing.

Answer (score 3):

To find which lastnames have duplicates:

```
  SELECT lastname, COUNT(lastname) AS rowcount 
    FROM table 
GROUP BY lastname 
  HAVING rowcount > 1
```

To delete one of the duplicates of all the last names. Run until it doesn't do anything. Not very graceful.

```
DELETE FROM table 
 WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
                FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS t 
            GROUP BY lastname 
              HAVING COUNT(lastname) > 1)
```

Comment: Now write that as a delete please. :)

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote simply because of the crappy second query. Surely there must be a simpler way then to re-run a query until it stops.

Answer (score 0):

dup [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

```
DELETE names
FROM names
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(RowId) as RowId, lastname 
   FROM names
   GROUP BY lastname 
) as KeepRows ON
   names.lastname = KeepRows.lastname 
WHERE
   KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```

assumption: you have an `RowId` column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as mycountvar FROM names GROUP BY lastname WHERE mycountvar > 1;
```

and then

```
DELETE FROM names WHERE lastname = '$mylastnamevar' LIMIT $mycountvar-1
```

but: why don't you just flag the fielt "lastname" als unique, so it isn't possible that duplicates can come in?

Comment: Because duplicates are already in the table. I'm trying to add `lastname` as a `UNIQUE INDEX`.